# Mkdir: missing operand on ubuntu 14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell, ubuntu

On make a directory on a ubuntu 14, the shell spits out this Mkdir: missing operand
someone know witch operand the is talking about?

```
Mkdir -p && chown -R ubuntu: && chmod + rw
Mkdir: missing operand
```

the capistrano script

```
mkdir -p #{pids_path} && chown -R #{user}:#{group} #{pids_path} && chmod +rw #{pids_path}
mkdir -p #{sockets_path} && chown -R #{user}:#{group} #{sockets_path} && chmod +rw #{sockets_path
```

Comment: You appear to be using `#` where you should be using `$`.

Comment: this is a capistrano script

Comment: doing a shell execution

Comment: `#{...}` is Ruby syntax for doing interpolation of an expression in a string. Your script looks like raw shell code.

Comment: @chepner, yes, is a capistrano deployment script, outputing a raw shell code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, but from what I can tell there is nil in `pids_path`. Your capistrano script has this:

```
mkdir -p #{pids_path} && chown -R #{user}:#{group} #{pids_path} && chmod +rw #{pids_path}
```

and if it's turning into this:

```
Mkdir -p && chown -R ubuntu: && chmod + rw
```

then you can see that the shell script was expecting something to come after the `mkdir -p` and before the `&&` and yet there isn't anything.

Incidentally, this means you're telling your shell to "make a directory called nothing" which is why it's failing

Comment: The group also appears to be empty.